# Can't find what's causing access violation in array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, winapi, jagged-arrays

!!!I have to stick with these functions as I'm not allowed to use any different!!!

A little explanation what I need to do: user input a search directory, then if nothing was found an error message pops up. If something is found, I create an array of one row because at least one file was found and it saves the name of found file. Then if FindNextFIle finds anything I add one row to existing array and this new row saves new found file name.

First output is direct output from the function and the second one is test output of the array to be sure that it worked correctly. Yet it doesn't work saying that memory access is violated so I can't work further.

There's probably 2 reasons why it's not working correctly:

1. Incorrect add of new row
2. incorrect print array function

Here's the `main()`:

```
system("chcp 1251");
    
    drtctrAr drctr;
    drctr = createDAr();

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;

    hf = FindFirstFile(drctr.str, &FindFileData);
    while (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!\n Try changing the search directory or correct your input!\n");
        return 1;

        break;
    }
    
    StringArray fileNames;
    int len;
    fileNames.str = (wchar_t**)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t*) * fileNames.rows);
    
    len = wcslen(FindFileData.cFileName)+1;
    fileNames.sym = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
    wcscpy_s(fileNames.sym, len, FindFileData.cFileName);

    while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Found file: %ls", FindFileData.cFileName);
        printf("\n");

        fileNames.rows++;

        fileNames.str = (wchar_t**)realloc(fileNames.str, sizeof(wchar_t*) * (fileNames.rows));
        int len = wcslen(FindFileData.cFileName) + 1;
        fileNames.str[fileNames.rows-1] = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
        wcscpy_s(fileNames.str[fileNames.rows-1], len, FindFileData.cFileName);
    }
    FindClose(hf);
    freeDAr(drctr);

    printSA(fileNames);
    filterSA(fileNames);
    freeSA(fileNames);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

And this is the print function in separate `.cpp`:

```
void printSA(StringArray arr)
{
    printf("...........................\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr.sym[i];j++)
            printf("Current file: %ls", arr.str[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And the array struct itself, forgot to add it:

```
struct StringArray
{
    wchar_t** str = NULL;
    wchar_t* sym = NULL;
    int rows = 1;
};
```

I mentioned both probable reasons sadly it doesn't mean that these are the correct guess, something at the very start of allocating the array may be wrong

Comment: What is `StringArray`?  And why not simply `std::vector<std::wstring>` instead of the low-level `C`-style coding using `malloc`?

Comment: Where does it crash according to the debugger?

Comment: What is `arr.sym[i]` supposed to be? Why are you using it as `j < arr.sym[i]`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, do you remember that C-style strings in C++ are supposed to be ***null-terminated***?

Comment: `std::vector<std::wstring> fileNames;
while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0) 
    fileNames.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);` -- and that is all that's needed.

Comment: You've tried to do things the hard way (malloc/realloc etc) and you have a bug. So now it the time to learn how to do things the easy way with `std::vector<std::wstring>`. At the moment your code is C not C++, so this is a good time to learn a bit of C++.

Comment: And why are you using your own explicit memory handling for both arrays and strings? Why aren't you using `std::vector` and `std::wstring`? C++ is so much more than just "C with classes".

Comment: I can't use any of object-oriented functions as it's part of my course project.  would wish to but I'm not allowed to. I have to stick with these functions, `std::vector` is not a part of the first course program and I'm doing a course project for the first year. Again I wish I could but I can't use anything from the second course

Comment: Anyway there is one bug here `fileNames.sym = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len); wcscpy_s(fileNames.sym, len, FindFileData.cFileName);` should be `fileNames.sym = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * (len + 1)); wcscpy_s(fileNames.sym, len + 1, FindFileData.cFileName);` as already pointed out by SomeProgrammerDude but maybe you missed it.

Comment: @john nope it does not change anything, Still access violation error on `printf("Current file: %ls", arr.str[i][j]);` in printSA

Comment: @ssbssa It crashes at `printf("Current file: %ls", arr.str[i][j]);` in print function

Comment: Maybe the problem is the `StringArray` object, but you haven't posted that. Really I think you should learn how to use a debugger. It's hard for anyone else to debug your code if they can only see part of it.

Comment: @Alfredison OK well the problem is not there.

Comment: Try `printf("Current file: %ls", arr.str[i]);` instead, but remove the inner for loop.

Comment: @Alfredison If you don't know how to use a debugger, then stick print statements all over the place, eventually you will track it down (although using a debugger would be much quicker).

Comment: @ssbssa now it's even showing `ucrtbased.pdb not loaded` page

Comment: @john The problem is his print statement is crashing.

Comment: @ssbssa I just understood that I was trying to compare j with the line. I used ther same method of creating array for int** array but that line was containing the number of the numbers in line! Probably I copied my own code wrong!

Comment: @ssbssa no it's still crashing exactly at the print function. Phew I'm not that much of a dummy

Comment: @ssbssa print statement crashing in one place does not mean it will crash everywhere. In fact the point at which it starts crashing is (probably) close to the point where the corruption has occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> fileNames.str = (wchar_t**)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t*) * fileNames.rows);
>
> len = wcslen(FindFileData.cFileName)+1;
> fileNames.sym = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
> wcscpy_s(fileNames.sym, len, FindFileData.cFileName);
> ```

This issue exists in above lines. You allocate memory for `str` but you don't allocate memory for `*str` / `str[0]` which is type of `wchar_t*`. Then you copy file name to `fileNames.sym` instead of `fileNames.str[0]`, so you don't find the error at first place. Then if second file is found, you allocate memory for `fileNames.str[1]` and copy the file name to it. This part is correct.

**So the access violation excepion happens when you try to access the content of `fileNames.str[0]` because it is non-allocated memory.** If you print `fileNames.str[1]`, it will success.

The following is modified version based on your presented code. It works for me. You can have a try.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct StringArray
{
    wchar_t** str;
    int rows;
}StringArray;

void printSA(StringArray arr)
{
    printf("...........................\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.rows; i++)
    {
        printf("Current file: %ls", arr.str[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;

    hf = FindFirstFile(L"D:\\*.txt", &FindFileData);
    while (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!\n Try changing the search directory or correct your input!\n");
        return 1;

        break;
    }

    StringArray fileNames;
    fileNames.rows = 1;
    int len;
    fileNames.str = (wchar_t**)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t*) * fileNames.rows);

    len = wcslen(FindFileData.cFileName) + 1;

    fileNames.str[fileNames.rows - 1] = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
    wcscpy_s(fileNames.str[fileNames.rows - 1], len, FindFileData.cFileName);

    while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0)
    {
        printf("Found file: %ls", FindFileData.cFileName);
        printf("\n");

        fileNames.rows++;

        fileNames.str = (wchar_t**)realloc(fileNames.str, sizeof(wchar_t*) * (fileNames.rows));
        int len = wcslen(FindFileData.cFileName) + 1;
        fileNames.str[fileNames.rows - 1] = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
        wcscpy_s(fileNames.str[fileNames.rows - 1], len, FindFileData.cFileName);
    }
    FindClose(hf);

    printSA(fileNames);

    // TODO: Free pointers
    // ...

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]